# What does spark-shell give "warning: there was one deprecation warning" while creating SQLContext?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create SQLContext inside Spark-shell using the command below:

```
//To start Spark Shell:

>spark-shell

//To create object of SQLContext

>val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

I am getting the Warning below:

```
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
sqlcontext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@17e2e5d
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Which version of spark are you using? Also, sqlContext is initialized by spark-shell on its own. You don't need to create it again.

Comment: I am using Spark-2.0.0. You mean to say I should use 'sc' instead of sqlcontext

Comment: In spark 2.0 sqlContext and sc got deprecated by 'spark' session. Now sc is initialized as 'spark' and if you want to use sqlContext, you can use it by calling spark.sqlContext

Comment: Thanks For answer and explanation anshul

Answer (score 6):

If you use Spark **2.0.0** you don't have to create a separate `SQLContext` yourself as it's available already.

```
scala> spark.sqlContext
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext = org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@45f32b12
```

`spark` above is also created automatically and is the **recommended way** to use the features of Spark SQL as of Spark 2.0 (see [SparkSession](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession)).

The reason for the deprecation warning is exactly to tell you to stay away from `SQLContext`.

> warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details

See [SQLContext's scaladoc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext) where it says:

> The entry point for working with structured data (rows and columns) in Spark 1.x.
>
> As of Spark 2.0, this is replaced by SparkSession. However, we are keeping the class here for backward compatibility.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation Jacek

Comment: @VishalSharma Accept the answer when you find time. Thanks.